# lmfit composite function with possibly different functional forms

Tags: python, lmfit

I am new to Python and currently working on a project where I need to estimate the parameters of a function that has is composed by possibly several factors:

Y(X; \theta) = g(X_g;\theta_g) \cdot h(X_h;\theta_h)\cdot f(X_f;\theta_f) \cdot l(X_l;\theta_l) \  + \epsilon

where g, h,f and l are functions that depend on the its parameters \theta_g, \theta_h, \theta_f, \theta_l.

In my case each of these functions can have different functional forms and the dimension of its parameters might vary, i.e. in case case \theta_g might have dimension 4 but for a particular case \theta_g will be fixed to 1. The same applies to the other functions h,f, and l.

I would also like to have flexibility to fix the parameters in case I want to keep them at certain values and optimize with respect to other ones.

It seems that the package lmfit and classes like Model and Parameters should allow me to achieve this. Yet, I would like some guidance on how to structure the various function such that I can use fitlm.

```
def fun_base(inc,par_base,type_fun_base):

    a0,a1,a2,a3 = par_base

    #base_f = 0
    if type_fun_base == 'Not used':
        base_f = 1
        #When the associated factor is not used, return a constant 1. 
    elif type_fun_base == 'Double breaking point':
         inc=inc/100 # this is for the case when incentive has a unit %
         base_f = np.minimum(a3, a0+a1*np.maximum(inc-a2, 0))
    elif type_fun_base  == 'Double-asymptotic':
        base_f = a0+ a1/(1+np.exp(a2+a3*inc))
        #the values of tge double-asymptotic function w.r.t. incentive
    elif type_fun_base =='CPR':
        base_f=a0
        #Return a constant param(1) no matter what the observation is 
    else:
        print("The rate incentive function has not been defined")
        sys.exit()
    return base_f

def fun_seasoning(age,par_season,type_fun_seasoning):
    s0,s1,s2,s3 = par_season
    if type_fun_seasoning == 'Not used':
        seasoning_f = 1
        #When the associated factor is not used, return a constant 1. 
    elif type_fun_seasoning  == 'Hockey stick':
        seasoning_f=np.minimum(s0+1/s1*age, 1)
    elif type_fun_seasoning  == 'Quadratic':
        seasoning_f = (1+s0+s1*age+ s2*age**2)
    elif type_fun_seasoning == 'Exponential AU':
        seasoning_f=s0*(1+np.exp(-s1*age)-np.exp(-s2*age))
    else:
        print("The seasoning function has not been defined")
        sys.exit()
    return seasoning_f


def prep_function(X,par,type_funs):
    par_base = par[0:4]
    inc = X[:,0]
    type_fun_base = type_funs[0]
    par_seasoning = par[4:]
    age = X[:,1]
    type_fun_seasoning = type_funs[1]
    ppr = fun_base(inc,par_base,type_fun_base)*fun_seasoning(age,par_seasoning,type_fun_seasoning)
    return ppr
```

prep_function represents Y(X,\theta) and the other two functions are the first two pieces in the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Updated to reflect the fact that your model components use different independent variables (`age`, `inc`, ...).

Part of what you are asking about how to allow flexibly creating fitting models with some variations in what functions are used to build the model.   I recommend building component model functions with meaningful argument names, perhaps (forgive me if these are incomplete or don't exactly meet your definitions -- the goal is to illustrate the approach):

```
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Model
from lmfit.models import ConstantModel

## Base models, depending on independent variable 'inc'
def double_break(inc, offset, amp, breakpoint, maxval=3, age=None):
     return np.minimum(maxval, offset+amp*np.maximum(inc - breakpoint, 0))

def double_asymptote(inc, offset, amp, decay_off, decay_slope, age=None):
     return offset + amp/(1.0+np.exp(decay_off+decay_slope*inc))

def constant(inc, c, age=None):
     return c

## Seasoning models, depending on independent variable 'age'
def hockey_stick(age, offset, slope, maxval=1, inc=None):
    return np.minimum(offset + slope/age, maxval)

def quadratic(age, offset, slope, quad, inc=None):
    return (offset + slope*age * quad*age*age)

def exponential_au(age, amp, decay1, decay2, inc=None):
    return amp*(1+np.exp(-decay1*age) - np.exp(-decay2*age))
```

each of these functions can be turned into a `lmfit.Model` that will then have parameter names that are more meaningful than `s1`, etc and can be run individually for testing.   With these definitions, you could then have a `build_model()` function that might look like

```
def build_model(base='double_break', seasoning='hockey_stick'):
   if base == 'double_break':
       basemodel = Model(double_break, prefix='base_', independent_vars=['inc', 'age'])
   elif base == 'double_asymptote':
       basemodel = Model(double_asymptote, prefix='base_', independent_vars=['inc', 'age'])
   else:
       basemodel = Model(constant, prefix='base_', independent_vars=['inc', 'age'])

   if seasoning == 'hockey_stick':
       smodel = Model(hockey_stick, prefix='seasoning_', independent_vars=['inc', 'age'])
   elif seasoning == 'quadratic':
       smodel = Model(quadratic, prefix='seasoning_', independent_vars=['inc', 'age'])
   else:
       smodel = Model(exponential_au, prefix='seasoning_', independent_vars=['inc', 'age'])

   return basemodel*smodel
```

The model this function builds will be the composite model (base*seasoning), and the parameters made with

```
   model = build_model(base='double_break', seasoning='quadratic')
   params = model.make_params(base_offset=1, base_amp=2,base_breakpoint=1000,
                              seasoning_offset=1, seasoning_slope=0.02, seasoning_quad=0)
```

will have more meaningful names like `base_offset`,  `seasoning_offset`, `seasoning_slope`, etc.   To use this model, you could do

```
   inc = np.linspace(-1, 1, 11)
   age = np.linspace(5, 10, 11)

   test = model.eval(params, age=age, inc=inc)
   result = model.fit(ydata, params, age=age, inc=inc)
```

It would be pretty easy to add new function options for the 'base' or 'seasoning', or to add another component to the model.

There is one thing about this model that may not match your use-case, depending on what you mean by "\cdot". That is, these model components are simply multiplied and so that the independent variables need to be the same length.   If you have 1000 `inc` values and 10 `age` values, it is not clear how you want to multiply those two function. If you need to do some other product or combination of component models other than basic addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division, you can do that, but it would require additional steps to supply the operator function used to combine the component models.  Consult the lmfit docs (with an example doing convolution) for details on that.

Comment: I also would like to have the flexibility to set some of the parameters to be fixed according to a list of booleans. To be more precise, I read characteristics of the model and of the optimization from an excel file. From this excel files I can read which parameters should be fixed and which not. It seems that I should do it using parname.vary. probably in combination with a for loop?

Comment: I would not recommend using an excel file as a fit configuration format.  That will lead to the end of civilization.   I would recommend Python or yaml for config files. But having your "build base model function" set which parameters to fix is a fine approach -- I do that myself sometimes.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't avoid using excel. Maybe I missed a point from the above answer. When I have to fit the model using model.fit the syntax requires to pass the dependent variables, the paramenter names and the name of the independent variables. For instance in the above example I would have:
`model = build_model(base='double_break', seasoning='quadratic')         
params = model.make_params()
out = mod.fit(y, params, x=x)`

in my case x might contain more than one variable, would the above syntax recognize that the first colum refers to the variable of the first function and so on?

Comment: Ah, I may have misunderstood your original question.  `lmfit.Model` is able to make composite models if the independent variable(s) are the same for all models.  So you would have to declare *all* independent variables for all model functions and models, and then use only the appropriate one per model.   I will update my answer...

Comment: I see that you already pass starting point to params. Would it be possible to pass starting point stored in an array? I am asking this because the `params = model.make_params(base_offset=1, base_amp=2,base_breakpoint=1000,
                              seasoning_offset=1, seasoning_slope=0.02, seasoning_quad=0)` creates a dictionary and if I want to access elements with a loop in happens in a pseudo-random way in python if I understood correctly.

Comment: @AlePo88 the short answer would be "of course not, that makes no sense, what are you actually trying to do?".  A longer answer would not fit in a comment. Ask a separate question.  Also, if the current answer does not sufficiently answer your current question and you feel the need to continually add to the original question, you may be better off using a different forum, such as the mailing list associated with the library.